# user inputs ipython

Tags: sorting, input, ipython

If I want a user to enter a number, I could have

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
```

What if I want the user to enter 10 numbers that can be sorted later.  How could I prompt the user to enter 10 integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.split()` to split up the string of numbers and then turn each one into an integer:

```
nums = [int(num) for num in raw_input('Enter some numbers: ').split(',')]
```

Or you can use `ast.literal_eval()` and input a Python object:

```
from ast import literal_eval

nums = literal_eval(raw_input('Enter some numbers: '))  # Type in [1, 2, 3]
```

The least safe method would be to use `input`, which passes the results of `raw_input()` into `eval()`:

```
nums = input('Enter some numbers: ')  # Type in [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: But getting the input using literal_eval shows `nums` as a string and not an array.. So what will you do to split the numbers?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: If you type in `[1, 2]`, you'd get back a Python object.

Answer (score 0):

Use alist

```
a=[]
i=0
while i<10:
    c=int(raw_input('Enter an integer:'))
    a.append(c)
    i+=1
```

This will ask the user for 10 integers and store it in an array. Sorting can be done easily in python using `a.sort()`